# Good reference for Roxygen?

Tags: r, documentation, reference, roxygen

Other than the excellent SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310409/how-can-i-document-data-sets-with-roxygen), and the Roxygen [manual](http://roxygen.org/roxygen-manual.pdf) and [vignette](http://roxygen.org/roxygen.pdf), is there any particularly thorough guide to using Roxygen?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm working on a [guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html) (but it's still incomplete).

A more comprehensive set of vignettes have been added [to the package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html), and were made available on CRAN as of version 4.0.0.

Answer (score 8):

The [user2010](http://user2010.org/) [tutorial](http://user2010.org//tutorials/Danenberg.html) that was presented by the roxygen authors is available [here](http://roxygen.org/useR/). It's not really a thorough guide, but still very useful I think.

Answer (score 3):

Even with the refrences above, I still had trouble finding a good kickstarter example until I found this other 
[Github](https://github.com/yihui/roxygen2) page.

Comment: I realize that this is an old question, but thought that we needed a more modern answer.