# How to create a roxygen documentation?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I begin to learn how to use roxygen, so I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523826/3279996) by @hadley and go down to this tutorial page: 
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html

For doing the first example, I created a new project and a new test.R file.

I copied these example code to test.R:

```
#' Add together two numbers.
#' 
#' @param x A number.
#' @param y A number.
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}.
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1)
#' add(10, 1)
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

After that, I run in console:

```
devtools::document()
```

But I got an error message:

> Error: No description at D:\Conny\RStudio\try/DESCRIPTION

What I did wrong? Even I manually created "DeSCRIPTION" file, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to create the package first - [see here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html)

Comment: Hi @RichardScriven, do you mean I need to creat a package at first? Actually I tried it: I used `package.skeleton('try')`, it created a new sub folder 'try' sub folder. In this 'try' folder, there are many files, I don't know, what shall I do with so many files

Comment: If you're following Hadley's writings, I suggest doing it in RStudio, where it is actually much easier imo.  Just create a new project/package and follow the prompts.   The DESCRIPTION file will be created in the proper place

Comment: @RichardScriven, thanks very much for the suggestion, I will follow the Hadley's instruction. :D

Comment: It also looks like `package.skeleton("try", code_files = "test.R")` might work as well