# Package .Rd files using roxygen2 package

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I have a question about creating an .Rd file for my R package using the `roxygen2` package.

It is clear to me that, for documenting R functions, I can use C-c C-o in emacs to generate comments above the function, and then fill them out, followed by `roxygenize("pkg")`. In this way, I have .Rd files for the R functions. However, I am not sure how can I get .Rd file for the data examples and the package itself? Currently, I am using `prompt("data")` to generate **data.Rd** and `promptPackage("pkg")` to generate **pkg-package.Rd**. I have to put these files into the `man` folder, and then edit them separately. How can I document data and package in a similar way like documenting R functions using `roxygen2`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For data, see [this previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310409/how-can-i-document-data-sets-with-roxygen) which suggests:

```
#' This is data to be included in my package
#'
#' @name data-name
#' @docType data
#' @author My Name \email{blahblah@@roxygen.org}
#' @references \url{data_blah.com}
#' @keywords data
NULL
```

I would suspect that you can do the same for `pkg-package.Rd`.  If it *must* be in roxygen format, consider

- a manual translation or
- the [rd2roxygen package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rd2roxygen/index.html).

Comment: Thank you Dirk for the helpful suggestions! I used `prompt()` and `promptPackage()` to generate .Rd files, and then use `rd2roxygen` package to translate the .Rd files into `roxygen` format, both for the data and for the package itself. They work perfectly :)