# How to put datasets into an R package

Tags: r, dataset, r-package

I am creating my own R package and I was wondering what are the possible methods that I can use to add (time-series) datasets to my package. Here are the specifics:

I have created a package subdirectory called *data* and I am aware that this is the location where I should save the datasets that I want to add to my package. I am also cognizant of the fact that the files containing the data may be .*rda*, *.txt*, or *.csv* files.

Each series of data that I want to add to the package consists of a single column of numbers (eg. of the form 340 or 4.5) and each series of data differs in length.

So far, I have saved all of the datasets into a *.txt* file. I have also successfully loaded the data using the *data()* function. Problem not solved, however.

The problem is that each series of data loads as a factor except for the series greatest in length. The series that load as factors contain missing values (of the form '.'). I had to add these missing values in order to make each column of data the same in length. I tried saving the data as unequal columns, but I received an error message after calling *data()*.

A consequence of adding missing values to get the data to load is that once the data is loaded, I need to remove the NA's in order to get on with my analysis of the data! So, this clearly is not a good way of doing things.

Ideally (I suppose), I would like the data to load as numeric vectors or as a list. In this way, I wouldn't need the NA's appended to the end of each series.

How do I solve this problem? Should I save all of the data into one single file? If so, in what format should I do it? Perhaps I should save the datasets into a number of files? Again, in which format? What is the best practical way of doing this? Any tips would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. But, if you edit your data in your favorite format and save with

```
save(myediteddata, file="data.rda")
```

The data should be loaded exactly the way you saw it in R.

To load all files in data directory you should add

```
LazyData: true
```

To your DESCRIPTION file, in your package.

If this don't help you could post one of your files and a print of the format you want, this will help us to help you ;)

Comment: Thanks, user1265067. Your suggestion has helped me a lot. In the end, I decided to save each series, in my preferred format, as separate .rda files. This method works a charm for me. Now I can move on to creating .rd files and putting them into the man subdirectory in order to describe the datasets in my package. Cheers! By the way, apologies for not making my question easy to understand - it was a difficult problem to put into words.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh: Can you explain how did you use these .rda files in your code? Is it possible to use .rds files?

Comment: @Ankit Use the load() function to load the data into the workspace. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Working_with_data_frames#Reading_and_saving_data This helps?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to saving as rda files you could also choose to load them as numeric with:

```
 read.table( ... , colClasses="numeric")
```

Or as non-factor-text:

```
 read.table( ..., as.is=TRUE) # which does pretty much the same as stringsAsFactors=FALSE
 read.table( ..., colClasses="character")
```

It also appears that the `data` function would accept these arguments sinc it is documented to be a simple wrapper for `read.table(..., header=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred saving location of your data depends on its format.

As [Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) suggested:

> - If you want to store binary data and make it available to the user,
>     put it in `data/`. This is the best place to put example datasets.
> - If you want to store parsed data, but not make it available to the
>     user, put it in `R/sysdata.rda`. This is the best place to put data
>     that your functions need.
> - If you want to store raw data, put it in `inst/extdata`.

I suggest you have a look at the linked chapter as it goes into detail about working with data when developing R packages.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the data file and include it in the R package, and you may want to also document it. Here's how to do both.

#### Create the data file and include it in R package

- Create a directory inside the package called `/data` and place any data in it. Use [only `.rda` and `.RData` files](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html).
- When creating the rda/RData file from an R object, make sure the R object is named what you want it to be named when it's used in the package and use `save()` to create it. Example:

```r
save(river_fish, file = "data/river_fish.rda", version = 2)
```

- Add this on a new line in the file called `DESCRIPTION`:

```
LazyData: true
```

#### Documenting the dataset

[Document the dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22598293/5783745) by placing a string with the dataset name after the documentation:

```r
#' This is data to be included in my package
#'
#' @author My Name \email{blahblah@@roxygen.org}
#' @references \url{data_blah.com}
"data-name"
```

[Here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/data-bands.R) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/data-storms.R) are some nice examples from dplyr.

---

#### Notes

- To access the data in the package, run `river_fish` or whatever the name of the dataset is. Nothing more is needed.
- Using `version = 2` when calling `save()` ensures your data object is available for older R versions (i.e. prior to 3.5.0) i.e. it will prevent this warning:

> WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.

- **No need** to use `load()` in the R package (just call the object directly instead e.g. `river_fish` will be enough to yield the data from `data/river_fish.rda`), but in the event you do wish to load an rda/RData file for some reason (e.g. playing around or testing), this will do it:

```
load("data/river_fish.rda")
```

- Informative sources [here](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22598293/5783745)