# Data not found in documentation with roxygen2

Tags: r, documentation, devtools, roxygen2

I am working with `roxygen2` library and `devtools`. Building a package with the following structure:

- Inside **/data** folder I have two **.rda** files with the information of each dataset. Let's call them `data1.rda` and `data2.rda`.
- Inside **/R** folder I have two files, one with the functions created (and their explanation) and another one called **data.R** with the information of each dataset.

  ```
  #' Description 1
  #'
  #' Simple definition
  #'
  #' @format The \code{data.frame} contains 2 variables:
  #' \describe{
  #'   \item{a}{The first variable.}
  #'   \item{b}{The second variable.}
  #' }
    "data1"
  ```

When I run `roxygen2::roxygenize()` I get this message:

> First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically... 
>   Error in get(name, envir = env) : object 'data1' not found.

I have looked for similar questions, without an answer for this problem. Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Does it work if you add `@keywords data` to the end of `#'` block?

Comment: @pdil  No, it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have that empty line in your actual roxygen comments?

Comment: No, I don't. I have edited the line not to confuse.

Comment: Typically doesn't one just use NULL under the roxygen documentation for datasets?  If you do that does it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310409/how-can-i-document-data-sets-with-roxygen

Comment: @Dason Thank you, It worked following the suggested link. It is strange that the traditional way indicated in http://blog.runsheng.xyz/attachment/r-packages.pdf doesn't work.

Comment: @R18 that's weird, in my package I used the data set name in quotes and it worked, https://github.com/pdil/usmap/blob/master/R/datasets.R

Comment: I suggested that since it seems the issue is that it's trying to "get" the data from the name you provide and that causes an error. I don't deal with including data enough to have a good example to play around with this but it seemed like avoiding that step would help alleviate this particular problem (but it seems like it shouldn't have been a problem so it might just be creating a problem later on). You might want to check that your package can install fine and the data gets loaded properly and you can view the documentation for the data.

Comment: I wonder if it's because you were missing `@docType data`

Comment: @pdil I didn't write `@datatype` and `@name'. Could the problem come from this?

Comment: @R18 Not sure actually, if you go to this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html) and go to "Documenting datasets" he doesn't use any of those `@` words and even has the name in quotes.

Comment: @R18 is your package on github? It would be a lot easier to actually see your code than trying to guess at what could be going on.

Comment: @Dason No, I'm still developing the functions for the package. Without `@doctype` it still works. It is like if it prefers to give `@name` rather than defining it between `" "` at the end of the code.

Comment: @R18 It can be on github while still in development.  It would certainly make helping debug this issue easier for others :)

Answer (score 4):

It might be a silly question but are you running roxygenise on your loaded package? Meaning that you first run `devtools::load_all()`, and then `roxygen2::roxygenise()`.
I've seen a couple of people making this mistake on other posts.

Answer (score 0):

The `roxygen2::roxygenize` method does not load the package properly. But you can replace this step with `devtools::document(package_path)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding these additional tags in your comments: `@name, @docType,` and `@references`