# Generate a documentation for datasets used in examples in an R package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2, rtools

I am building an R package and in its documentation I included an example that uses two datasets (let's call them `dataset1` and `dataset2`).
I am now trying to write a documentation for these two datasets.
To achieve this, I saved the two datasets in the "data" subfolder with names `dataset1.RData` and `dataset2.RData` using the `save()` function, and also created and a file named `data.R` in the "man" folder with the following content:

```
#' Title for dataset 1
#'
#' description for dataset1
#'
#' @name dataset1
#' @keywords dataset1
#' @docType data
#' @format An S4 object of class RasterLayer.
#' @details
#'     details for dataset1
#'
"dataset1"

#' Title for dataset 2
#'
#' description for dataset1
#'
#' @format An S4 object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.
#' @name dataset2
#' @docType data
#' @details
#'     details for dataset2
#' \describe{
#'   \item{name_column_1}{description of column1}
#'   \item{name_column_1}{description of column1}
#' }
#'
"dataset2"
```

My package and the included examples check fine without any errors or warnings. However, when I run `?dataset1` or `?dataset2` I get the following message:

> No documentation for ‘dataset1’ in specified packages and libraries: you
> could try ‘??dataset1’

I there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `devtools::document()` before building? Did you actually install the packages or are you using the devtools shim to load it? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input at hat can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310409/how-can-i-document-data-sets-with-roxygen) might help.

Comment: You are missing an `@export`. Also you don't need a string at the end, `NULL` would do.

Comment: @MrFlick `devtools::document()` did the trick. Thank you for the suggestion. I am doing this thing for the first time and learning curve is not so gentle. Please do bear with me with such rookie questions. More will come I guarantee :)

Comment: I highly recommend that you read https://r-pkgs.org/