# How to inherit roxygen documentation from data

Tags: r, tidyverse, roxygen2

I have read about `roxygen2` inheritance with datasets and documenting data added to an R package [from the documentation](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-other.html?q=data#datasets) and from [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310409/how-can-i-document-data-sets-with-roxygen). However, I cannot figure out how to inherit documentation between datasets.

I have one data set, `data1`, with 3 columns and 100 rows. I have another data set, `data2`, with 5 columns and 75 rows. `data2` includes all columns in `data1`, with a couple extras. Here is an example of what the data look like:

```
data1
##>  A tibble: 100 × 3
#>   name  school grade
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 Joe   EHS    A
#> 2 Amy   EHS    B
#> 3 Sara  WHS    A
#etc...
```

```
data2
##>  A tibble: 75 × 5
#>   name  school grade gender sport     
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 Joe   EHS    A     M      basketball
#> 2 Amy   EHS    B     F      swimming
#> 3 Jack  EHS    C     M      football
#etc...
```

Here is how I have `data1` documented:

```
#' School Enrollment Data
#' 
#' School enrollment data for the 2018-2019 school year. 
#' 
#' @format A tibble with 100 rows and 3 columns:
#' \describe{
#'    \item{name}{Name of the student}
#'    \item{school}{Name of the school}
#'    \item{grade}{Grade of the student}
#' }
#' @source xyz
"data1"
```

How can I document `data2` using inheritance? I would like to create documentation without having to copy-paste from the documentation of `data1`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#' School Enrollment Detail Data
#' 
#' School enrollment detail data for the 2018-2019 school year.
#' 
#' ### Inheritance here?
#' 
#' @format A tibble with 75 rows and 5 columns:
#' \describe{
#'    \item{gender}{Gender of the student}
#'    \item{sport}{Sport of the student}
#' }
#' @source xyz and abc
"data2"
```

Comment: `@inheritSection data1 format` See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/reuse.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - "format" is not identified as a section by `roxygen2`, so this produces an error

Comment: maybe `@inherit data1` will work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works well! I can put the fields from `data1` in a `@section` and then use `@inheritSection` to include this in the `data2` documention.

The code looks like:

```
#' School Enrollment Data
#' 
#' School enrollment data for the 2018-2019 school year. 
#' 
#' @format A tibble with 100 rows and 3 columns
#'
#' @section Data1 Fields:
#'   \describe{
#'      \item{name}{Name of the student}
#'      \item{school}{Name of the school}
#'      \item{grade}{Grade of the student}
#'   }
#'
#' @source xyz
#'
#' @docType data
"data1"

#' School Enrollment Detail Data
#' 
#' School enrollment detail data for the 2018-2019 school year.
#' 
#' @format A tibble with 75 rows and 5 columns
#'
#' @section Data2 Unique Fields:
#'   \describe{
#'      \item{gender}{Gender of the student}
#'      \item{sport}{Sport of the student}
#'   }
#'
#' @inheritSection data1 Data1 Fields
#'
#' @source xyz
#' @source abc
#'
#' @docType data
"data2"
```

Note that this removes the actual format of the data from the `@format` tag, so this may not align with best practices according to the documentation.